# How would humanity react to Intelligent animal life?

Tags: xenobiology, space-colonization, interspecies-relations

I know the title is misleading, but hear me out.

Let's say mankind has evolved past the frontiers of the Oort cloud, something like in the Avatar or Alien Universes. Enough to have jumping from stars be as mundane as taking a train ride between cities in the closest-to-earth, most developed areas, but enclaves or colonies of terraformers in the most barren.

Let's also say, going by the previous examples, that they find inhabitable planets with terran atmospheres that, while able to sustain life, are already inhabited by intelligent, sentient species which not only are not even close to prehistoric in technology, but also see little use to it physiologically. As if the whole world were a "What if" humans never existed, a look back to 50 million years ago or if Na'vi-like species were all around the place. Sort of hostile, but kinda nice overall.

From there, there's a crapton of ways to go. I'm aware of how some reserves or isolated populations are left alone due to worries in biological hazards as well as to avoid land claims, as well as it depending on who finds it or who funds the operations, as Military or Corporate could pretty much end up in a Na'Vi situation which I'm not particularly sure I want as the trope is kind of tiring.

If academia discovers it, which is the path I'd rather take, would we do the same we usually try to do with wild animals in our world in the sense of studying them as close as we can but without direct intervention like putting a tracking collar or sending a spy robot from orbit or from a colony? Would a hostile planet like this also have to take space poachers looking for the most dangerous game offworld into account? Not to mention how culture could be different and have the scientists pull a Fuegia Basket and HMS Beagle on the aliens.

I know it's a lot to cover, or try to, with as broad an approach as this is, but how do you think Academia could react or, if possible, try and minimize the footprint humanity leaves on such environment?

As always, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Edited to better focus the problem to simply Academia. Still, any help in finding a focus or a better way to summarize this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please just ask one question at a time, preferably in a clear and straightforward way. You should also know that "_would my fictional setting X have plot device Y_" is often entirely up to you, and not always a good fit for this site.

Comment: Not clear why anybody would think that the Tsinghua University, the Lomonosov University, and the University of California Berkeley would all have the same approach to the study and exploitation of a newly discovered world.

Comment: This is what we call a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868), which isn't a good fit for our site. Such questions violate (at least) the [help] rules that all answers can't be equally valid and that answers shouldn't be opinion-based (how even a small group of people would react is more opinion based than you might think). Finally, questions like this are too story-based (they're react the way you want them to). Simply put, it seems like you're asking a specific question, but you're really asking something very, very broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is worth the most?
If this Planet does not have any material on it, that is super rare, the opportunity to study it would outweigh the opportunity to strip mine it for its resources. Simply because a human race like you describe it has plenty of uninhabited planets to stripmine for minerals and such.

So the planets worth would actually be its possibility to be researched. Just think of the stuff we still find in rainforests to then discover it has this and that medical property and can be used to treat this and that desease. And that is valid for any planet with life on it, not to mention sentient life.

But what would sentient life change? We might decide to not interfere, like they do in star trek, it is their first directive, so pretty important. Unless for the times when they decide to not follow that directive, or when they accidentally reveal themselves to the aliens.

So there would be a bunch of scientists that are very eager to study this sentient life. Some of them would sure want to do it as non interfering as possible, maybe just what they can observe with their super high tech satelites.
Others would go for robots the size of flies (or the equivalent of flies of that alien planet), as they see the risk for the aliens to smash one of their robot flies and then to investigate that robot as quasi non existent.

But scientists are just people and just as people have different thoughts and ideas about what is the right thing to do, so would scientists have different thoughts and ideas on what is the right way to study the aliens. And as that is a spectrum you would almost certainly find some scientists, who actually  try to live with the aliens in order to research them. Think of Dian Fossey and her gorillas. There would probably even be some scientists who would abduct aliens to experiment on them in all kind of ways.

Those would probably repeat all psychologic experiments that have ever been done on humans with the aliens in order to compare them. Starting with the ones that were later considered immoral, like the Milgram Experiment or the prison experiment.

Comment: @Facundo zanatta next time, don't accept the first answer you get. Give the question a day or two, you never know what other answer you might get, maybe there will be one much more deserving it than mine ;)

Comment: Right, apologies. I'll still probably come around later on when the world is more than a broad idea.